# How can I get current zoom level from Google Map Api v2?

Tags: android, google-maps

We created an app that shows maps using Google Maps api.
However, I don't know how to get the current zoom level when the camera is moved.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(
            new LatLng(0, 0)
    ));

    googleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraIdle() {
            int zoomLevel = Math.round(mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),zoomlevel,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the current zoom this way:

```java
float zoom=googleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom;
```

Answer (score 2):

> get the zoom level

```
  final GoogleMapController googleMapController = await widget.completer.future;
      var  zoom = await googleMapController.getZoomLevel();
      print(zoom);
```